# How to search special character like french character from SQLite database

Tags: android

In my database i had one column as name, where in this column it has name of all recipe names with english and french character.
When i search a string like query:

```
Select recipe.name from recipe_table where name LIKE = %crepe%
```

it gives me no result. But it should return one result this-"crèpes"

So i need: search through english alphabet and give me result of all english + french alphabet , it means all result.

thank you in advance .

Comment: tow ways... One, use the character as is. two. Forget the caracter and put a `_`(single character wildcard) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of searching Spanish character I had created one more column as `name2` where i convert all Spanish name to English name.

And then I search English characters from column `name2`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that the encoding of the database must be UTF-8.

Then:

```
Select recipe.name from recipe_table where name LIKE = %crepe%
```

will find any values that have 'crepe' in any position, and you need 'crèpe'.
Possibly you can change french characters by _ .

```
 Select recipe.name from recipe_table where name LIKE = %cr_pe%
```

But I'm not sure.

Also there are some solutions:
1) Try to search how to rebuild android's sqlite with icu support.
2)  [Or use custom cursor wrapper like this](https://gist.github.com/ramzes642/5400792)